# Using OpenStreetMap data in an offline C# webforms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, maps, openstreetmap

As part of a project, I have to develop a offline C# application that can calculate the distance and journey time between two points. I'm planning on using data from OpenStreetMap but I'm not too sure what the process would involve. I do not want to use OSM's API but rather develop my own backend, to ensure continuity in case someone else decides to pick up the project to improve it. I have several questions:

- Where do I download a full map of the United Kingdom from the website?
- How would I overlay the postcodes, addresses, places of interests onto the map?
- How would this information be read by the C# application (i.e. when the user enters point A or B, it should be pulled from a central database and automatically calculate the distance and journey time between both)
- I want the information to be stored on the client side, without the need for a server - is this possible?

Comment: Hello sir did you manage to do Openstreetmap in Asp.net 4.0 aspx? And dynamically map lat and lon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ask only one question at a time.

Question 1: OSM offers various ways for [downloading data](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data). In your case you should download a [country extract](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts).

Question 2: For displaying a map either use [raster tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) or [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles). But before that you should decide whether you want to [render your own tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) (in which case you will need some kind of [tile server](http://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/)) or [use available tiles from the web](http://switch2osm.org/using-tiles/) (in which case you will need constant access to the web).

Question 3: Ideally your C# application will just query a local [PostgreSQL](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostgreSQL)/[PostGIS](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PostGIS) database.

Question 4: Which information? Everything? That would require lots of resources on the client for storing and querying the data.

Comment: Hello sir did you manage to do Openstreetmap in Asp.net 4.0 aspx? And dynamically map lat and lon?